# Merge questions

Tags: support, status-completed, exact-duplicates

Mea culpa. I [posted](https://superuser.com/questions/369826) a question here a while ago, didn't get any responses, so I posted again over at stackoverflow. However, that post was [migrated](https://superuser.com/questions/376765) back here, so now I have two pretty-much identical questions. To complicate matters, I subsequently put a bounty on the first version of the post. Can they still be merged, or can someone simply delete the first version (after which I'll put the bounty on the second version, add more detail, respond to comments, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Done, the version without a bounty is no more

Comment: Thanks very much!